# PHP post all form inputs without creating variables for each

Tags: php, post

Usually when I use PHP I create a variable and post statement for each form input like so:

```
   $myVar1 = $_POST["formItem1"];
   $myVar2 = $_POST["formItem2"];
   ect......
```

I know if i use:

```
  echo $_POST;
```

I can get all the key and values from the form inputs but I don't know how to use them in a script.

So I guess I have 2 questions:

1. How do I quickly post all form inputs without creating a variable for each input?
2. How do I use a posted in a script without having it assigned to a specific variable?

Comment: i dont really understand your question...can you be clearer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simply echo all the inputs, you can use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.'<br/>';
}
```

If you don't want to store them in variables, use arrays:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = $value;
}
```

Now, `$data` is an array containing all the data in `$_POST` array. You can use it however you wish.

Comment: What I would have said

Comment: Well lets say within my POST I have normal string values from a text field and array values from a group of check boxes.  How would I isolate the checkbox array so I can manipulate it?

Comment: @Austin: For that, you can simply do: `$checkBoxArray = $_POST['nameAttributeOfTheCheckbox'];`.

Comment: cool so use the foreach loop for all normal string posts and a individual post for arrays?

Comment: @Austin: It really depends on what you want to do. You could use `is_array()` inside the `foreach` to check if it's an array and loop it further. [Example](https://eval.in/70633).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign to a variable. You can use directly `$_POST['input_name']`

If you want to deal with each sended params, you can use foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
  echo "$key : $val <br/>";
}
```

Comment: using directly wont that expose the OP to security risks?

Comment: of course you need to checks all input datas before manipulating them. never trust any user inputs. But it's the same security risk than assigning to a var first

Answer (score 0):

for this instance of just quickly checking and testing i typically just use the `print_r()` function: **[documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)**

as quoted from the docs:

> print_r() displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans.

one line easy to toggle on and off (with comments)- no need to use any form of variables

`print_r($_POST);`

if i need my output nice and readable i like to expand it as follows:

```
function print_r2($x){
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($x);
     echo '</pre>';
}
```

and then you can call with: `print_r2($_POST);`

this way you get the pre-formatted text block on your html page and can see the line breaks and tabbed spacing provided from the `$_POST` object printout

Answer (score 0):

Another way to extract (besides the [extract function](https://www.php.net/extract)) variables is;

```
$array = array('foo'); // Which POST variables do you want to get
foreach($array as $key) {
    if(!isset(${$key})) { // Check if variable hasn't been assigned already
        ${$key} = $_POST[$key];
    }
}
echo $foo;
```

I would not recommend it because it can get quite messy to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

### View everything in `$_POST` is useful for debugging

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';
```

### Access a specific checkbox

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="something" name="ckbox[]" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="anotherthing" name="ckbox[]" checked>
```

**PHP**

```
echo $_POST['ckbox'][0]; // something
echo $_POST['ckbox'][1]; // anotherthing

// isolate checkbox array
$ckbox_array = $_POST['ckbox'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that allows you to access a specific $_POST item by name (key):

```
function get_post_value($name, $default)
{
    if ( isset($_POST[$name]) ) {
        return $_POST[$name];
    } else if ( $default ) {
        return $default;    
    }
    return null;
}
```

$default allows you to pass a value that can be used as a fallback if the key you specify isn't present in the $_POST array.

Now you can reference $_POST items without assigning them to a variable, and without worrying if they are set.  For example:

```
if ( get_post_value('user-login-submit', false) ) {
    // attempt to log in user
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `extract($_POST)`, it will create variables for you.

For example, you can have for the code you posted :

```
<?php

$_POST["formItem1"] = "foo";
extract($_POST);
echo $formItem1; // will display "foo"

?>
```

**EDIT** : it's not PHP `explode`, it's `extract`.

Comment: did you mean `extract` instead of `explode`?

Comment: `explode` on what? I think you're looking for `extract()`. I do **not** recommend this. It's a very bad idea.

Comment: No, I'm talking about explode :)

Comment: so you're wrong, explode is to transform a string into an array. for example `explode('-', 'a-b-c')` will result `array('a','b','c')`

Comment: Oh, I guess I'm having a bad day... Sorry for my mistake, it was `extract` :)